# Sling scheduler periodic job -- will the job overlap?

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler, sling

I am using Sling's scheduler to schedule periodic jobs and I'm wondering if I'm scheduling job A to run every 5 minute. In the unlikely occasion, the job start to run and took more than 5 minute what will happen? I have specified the job cannot run in parallel.

1. Job A will run again immediately after the previous run finishes.
2. Job A will run 5 minute after the previous run finishes.

Under the hood, Sling's scheduler is using QuartzScheduler, so if you know how QuartzScheduler will behave in this case please do share your knowledge as well.

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Quartz Scheduler 2.1.x the [annotation DisallowConcurrentExecution](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.1.5/org/quartz/DisallowConcurrentExecution.html) is used to prevent concurrent execution of the same Job.

In Quartz Scheduler 2.0.x in order to void the concurrent execution of a Job you have to implement the [StatefulJob interface](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.0.0/org/quartz/StatefulJob.html).

The decision on whether the misfired execution will execute when the previous job completes or it will be ignored **depends on the trigger's misfire policy**. By default when the scheduler starts, it searches for any persistent triggers that have misfired, and it then updates each of them based on their individually configured misfire instructions.

So in my opinion Job A will run again immediately after the previous run finishes. I suppose that Sling uses the default misfire policy. Otherwise the answer depends on the misfire policy selection.

That's how Quartz Scheduler works. I don't know how the Sling's scheduler works.

I hope this helps.